# Sending a paper cut command to a ESC/POS Printer after printing a .txt File

Tags: c#, printing, cut, epson, escpos

I made a system (using C# and WooCommerce Rest API) for a TakeAway Website to print a Ticket after a User orders products on a Website.

I am using the ****EPSON TMT20** II** Printer to print the Data. I am using the Printer as a Network Printer because I have to and printing Tickets is no Problem, I only have to cut the Paper after successfully printing a Ticket which is the Problem I have.

I am sending the Data via CMD Commands

> (example: *copy /b "D:...\order_n.txt" "\\Servername\Printername*")  -> *prints the Data I saved in a .txt File*

**is it possible to append the paper cut command to the .txt File that I am printing or is there another, more efficient way to cut the paper via C#?**

According to the Documentation **GS V 48** and **GS V 0** are the commands that can be used to cut the paper

> *https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87#gs_cv*

I tried using the RawPrinterHelper Class and sending the Cut Command Data as Bytes but it returns me Windows Error 1801 or rather I can't access the Printer in that way. I also tried to append the command the File I sent to the printer.

Any help would be appreciated! if I haven't been detailed enough please let me know!
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can print the .txt file with the raw ESC/POS command and the text to be printed, copy it to the server printer device, and have the server send it directly to the printer, then at the end of the file It seems that the paper can be cut simply by adding the ESC/POS command for cutting the paper.

In that case, please create the command according to the notes on the referenced page. The paper cut command must be in a state where no print request is made at the beginning of the line. Also, since there is a distance between the print head and the paper cutter, you will need to use the function B command to put an appropriate line break before the cut.

By the way, 0/48 in the reference pages, such as GS V 0 and GS V 48, is 0x00/0x30. If it is function B, it becomes 0x41/0x42, and the line feed number is specified after that.

Instead, if the program on the server converts the .txt file you sent to the server into a page image and then prints on the printer, you need to incorporate the mechanism you wrote to cut the paper. maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply kunif,

So if I understood everything correct in order to correctly cut the paper I have to put a line break before cutting it (The distance between the printer head and autocutter is ~11mm) and therefore using Function B instead of Function A,

Comment: I added some white spaces after printing the document but I will try it anyway,

When I append the command to the .txt File (later on it is Raw File) that I am printing, it basically just prints the command instead of cutting the paper. I also tried copying a second file to the Printer and put a time delay after printing the ticket, so that it doesen't cut while it's printing but it does the same thing

I appended the Command to the file like this: 
    sw_order.WriteLine("GS V 0x30");

please Note that it is the first Time that I have to use a receipt printer,
Thanks for your Help:)

Comment: By the way, as you know, please note that "GS V 0x30" is a 3-byte binary data that is 0x1D 0x56 0x30.

Comment: it is still just printing the command not executing it, I will try to use the RawPrinterHelper Class again to send the data to the Printer.

Comment: As for RawPrinterHelper, there are a few possibilities, but this article might be helpful. [Rawprinterhelper network printer ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7502350/9014308) For example, instead of directly specifying the printer on the server, try creating a device entry for the remote shared printer on the client machine and printing to it.

Answer (score 0):

It works now,

I just appended these lines of Code to the Text File that I am printing

```
string GS = Convert.ToString((char)29);
string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);
string COMMAND = "";
COMMAND = ESC + "@";
COMMAND += GS + "V" + (char)48;

sw.WriteLine(COMMAND);
```

Comment: There is a slight chance that bad things will happen if you initialize it with ESC@. Is it possible to use CRLF instead of ESC@?

Comment: Can you explain the whole code, since I was looking to such solution .

Comment: ESC@ is the initialization code for Epson receipt printers