# Do we take print from angular application with WebUSB API in Thermal Printer (MP-4200 TH)?

Tags: javascript, thermal-printer, escpos, webusb

Following is the Angular code of  app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

  private usbDevice: any;

  private textToProint: any[] = [
    'SIZE 48 mm,25 mm',
    'CLS',
    'TEXT 30,10,"4",0,1,1,"HackerNoon"',
    'TEXT 30,50,"2",0,1,1,"WebUSB API"',
    'PRINT 1',
    'END',
  ];

  async connect() {
    try {
      this.usbDevice = await (navigator as any).usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ VendorID: 0x0B1B, ProductID: 0x0003 }] });
      console.log('Connected to USB device:', this.usbDevice);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error connecting to USB device:', error);
    }
  }

  async disconnect() {
    try {
      if (this.usbDevice) {
        await this.usbDevice.close();
        console.log('Disconnected from USB device.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error disconnecting from USB device:', error);
    }
  }

  async send() {
    console.log(this.usbDevice, 'Sending');
    try {
      if (this.usbDevice) {
        console.log("USB device opened:", this.usbDevice.configuration.interfaces[1]);
        await this.usbDevice.open()
          .then(() => this.usbDevice.selectConfiguration(1))
          .then(() => this.usbDevice.claimInterface(this.usbDevice.configuration.interfaces[1]?.interfaceNumber))


        await this.usbDevice.transferOut(
          this.usbDevice.configuration.interfaces[1]?.alternate.endpoints.find((obj: any) => obj.direction === 'out').endpointNumber,
          new Uint8Array(
            new TextEncoder().encode(this.textToProint.join('\r\n'))
          )
        );
        await this.usbDevice.releaseInterface(0);
        await this.usbDevice.close();

        console.log("Data sent to printer:");
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error connecting to  printer:", error);
    }
  }

}
```

And I have app.component.html

```
<div>
  <body>
 <button style="background-color: blue; cursor: pointer; color: aliceblue; border-radius: 12px; margin: 2px; padding: 4px; align-items: center;" (click)="connect()">Connect to USB Device</button>
    <button style="padding: 4px; margin: 4px; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 12px; background-color: blueviolet; color: white;" (click)="send()">Send Data</button>
    <button style="padding: 4px; margin: 4px; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 12px; background-color: darkred; color: white;" (click)="disconnect()">Disconnect</button>
  </body>
</div>
```

I need to print a ticket in thermal printer (MP-4200 TH). I installed the driver and I can able to print the plain text via printer by above code. But I need to supply the ESC/POS command in to printer from angular typescript vis webUSB API . All I want to print and cut the ticket by printer itself.(Do we acheive this using web USB ? ). NOTE:  I referred this link -> https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-webusb-api-connecting-to-usb-devices-and-printing-with-tspltspl2

So the question became : Can we pass the ESC/POS command from angular application via WebUSB API to print the ticket and cut a ticket by itslef ?

Comment: Please edit this question to explain what isn't working and what steps you've tried to debug it. As written this question doesn't have a question in it.

Comment: @ReillyGrant, Hope now the question is understandable to you, I can print the plain text from angular app via webUSB API to printer. But i need to supply ESC/POC commands from angular application to printer (MP-4200 TH).

Comment: Well, aren't ESC/POS sequences just that..? Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63130679/51685 have you tried sending e.g. `\x27@\x29V\x30` to the printer?

Comment: The commands you're sending so far don't look like ESC/POS to me. Have you found a command reference for this printer? As AKX said, the commands will be sent as text along with the data to print.